# Mock never called

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I tried to implement a mock in my unit tests but it is never called, even though it should.

tests.py

```
from mock import patch

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        name = 'Test'

        with patch('my_module.my_file.my_function') as add_method:
            m = MyModel(name=name)
            m.save()

        add_method.assert_called_with(name=name)
```

models.py

```
from my_module.my_file import my_function

class MyModel(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=12)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_function(self.name)

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my_file.py

```
def my_function(name):
    # Processing...
```

When I run the unit test, it just tells me the mock has not been called, though it should be, I know the script works fine. Do you have any idea/advice for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `models` is imported, it runs `from my_module.my_file import my_function`, which is not mocked yet. When you run your test case, the `my_function` name in the `models` module is already bound to the *real* function: patching `my_files` has no effect.

What you need is to patch `models.my_function`:

```
with patch('models.my_function') as add_method:
    m = MyModel(name=name)
    m.save()
```

An alternative would be to patch `my_file.my_function` at `models` import time.

See [where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) documentation.